# Obtaining function's extreme values without derivate

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

What is other method to obtain a function min/max value without any use of derivative? 
For example in this function:

$f(x) = 4x + \dfrac{9\pi^2}{x} + \sin(x)$

My teacher used a method that goes something like this:

$a = 4x$, $\ \ \ $ $b = \dfrac{9\pi^2}{x}$, $\ \ \ \min = 2\sqrt{a \cdot b} - \sin(x)$.

Can anyone tell me name of such method?

Comment: If $a \geqslant 0, b \geqslant 0$, then

$$(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2 \geqslant 0,$$

$$a+b \geqslant 2\sqrt{a \cdot b}.$$

Comment: Hey, I asked the same question. Check out this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426569/maximum-of-a-trigonometric-function-without-derivatives

Answer (score 3):

There is a large collection of standard **Inequalities** that can be used in max/min problems.

One of the more useful ones is the Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Inequality (AM-GM). In the case $n=2$ it says that if $a$ and $b$ are positive then
$$\frac{a+b}{2}\ge \sqrt{ab},$$
with equality only if $a=b$. That  is essentially the fact that you quoted. Note that the inequality can be proved simply by starting from the fact that $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2\ge 0$, and then doing some manipulation.

The General AM-GM says that if the $a_i$ are positive then
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}\ge (a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{1/n},$$
with equality only when the $a_i$ are all equal.

There are many other inequalities useful for proving max/min results. For example, you might want to look up the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality. It so happens that the inequality your teacher used can be thought of as using the case $n=2$ of AM-GM or as using the case $n=2$ of C-S, though for larger $n$ they differ.

There are many other "named" inequalities. For a long list, look [here.]  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inequalities)

**Remark:** I strongly recommend the book *Maxima and Minima Without Calculus* by Ivan Niven.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will check it out, how do i know what is A and what is B? and why is Sin(x) thrown off?

Comment: It doesn't matter which of the first two terms you call $a$ and which you call $b$, the inequality is symmetric. The $\sin x$ does not fit nicely into the game. Indeed for a $3$ term thing like the one you are quoting, with a transcendental function mixed in, I would expect only estimates, not sharp results.

Comment: In above task they required me to get minimum value, and i couldn't solve it using derivative, however this method got a correct answer which is 12π - 1.

Comment: That's purely by "accident." The combination of the first two terms reaches a minimum at $x=3\pi/2$. That **happens** to be where $\sin x$ reaches a minimum. But if you modify the coefficients $4$ and/or $9\pi^2$ a little, and we can minimize the sum of the first two terms using the non-calculus approach, but the $\sin x$ now spoils things, and we are not able to find an "exact" answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Would you recommend that book for me (is it too hard)?

Comment: Abel's Proof? I think so. The nice somewhat old-fashioned book on Galois Theory is by Edwards. If you have access to a university library, you may want to look at it. At your current stage, there are other subjects that are more accessible.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I meant "Maxima and Minima Without Calculus by Ivan Niven". Also, do you know a good book on elementary number theory from which I could learn?

Comment: Niven is a good book, if that is a subject you are interested in. There are many books of course. Some very good elementary ones by very good Soviet mathematicians. Lots of good number theory books too, a nice start is the one by Silverman, a Friendly Introduction to Number Theory. I am sure there is lots of good stuff online by now also.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok thanks I'll try to hunt around

Answer (score 0):

Numerical methods do exist. For some reason, I haven't seen this method or any similar ones around, but just as you can use the Secant method to find the root by drawing a line between two points, finding the x-intercept, then repeating, you can find the extrema of a function by drawing a parabola between 3 points, finding the vertex, then repeating. If you were to evaluate this, you'd find the results look like:

$$x_n = \frac{y_{n-1}(x_{n-2}^2-x_{n-3}^2)+y_{n-2}(x_{n-3}^2-x_{n-1}^2)+y_{n-3}(x_{n-1}^2-x_{n-2}^2)}{2(y_{n-1}(x_{n-2}-x_{n-3})+y_{n-2}(x_{n-3}-x_{n-1})+y_{n-3}(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}))}$$

Or, if you're a fan of matrices:

$$x_n = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
x_{n-1}^2 & y_{n-1} & 1 \\
x_{n-2}^2 & y_{n-2} & 1 \\
x_{n-3}^2 & y_{n-3} & 1\end{vmatrix}}
{2\begin{vmatrix}
x_{n-1} & y_{n-1} & 1 \\
x_{n-2} & y_{n-2} & 1 \\
x_{n-3} & y_{n-3} & 1\end{vmatrix}}
$$

So, if you start with 3 initial x values sufficiently close to a local extremum, then use this method to iteratively calculate the next x, you should hopefully get close to the extremum. Much like the secant method, it doesn't always converge, especially if the initial 3 values chosen were not even close. It also usually fails to converge if the extremum occurs at an inflection point, much like how the secant method usually doesn't converge if the root occurs at an extremum.

Technically, while this method does require 3 initial values, you could cheat and just start with 2 initial values, then make $x_3 = \frac{x_1+x_2}2$. Just as the seeds of the secant method are basically the upper and lower bounds of the root (though sometimes, they do go out of bounds), here your two initial values will act as bounding boxes for your extremum (though again, it could go out of bounds if things aren't well behaved).

Similar to how the secant method has a convergence of the golden ratio (that is, the number of correct digits is expected to multiply by 1.618 each iteration), this method has a convergence of the [plastic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number) (the number ρ such that ρ+1=ρ³, equal to about 1.325). That is to say, it doesn't converge nearly as fast, in fact it converges about 1.7 times slower. But, it still converges superlinearly, so it is still a viable method. And, just like the secant method, it doesn't require you to already know one or more higher order derivatives.

However, if you do happen to already know higher order derivatives (and they're not extremely computationally expensive), it would definitely be recommended to use methods such as the secant method, Newton's method, or Halley's method to locate a root of the first derivative.

Upon evaluating this method through a program (testing it out on the function y = sin(x)cos²(x)), I found that most of the time, it converges to a few decimal places, then fluctuates. This is mostly due to roundoff: at a local extremum, the derivative is 0 and the y values are mostly the same, the difference between them is quadratically proportional to how much x is off by. A solution to this is to simply rearrange the terms in a way that leads to less roundoff. The most reliable approach I found was the following:

$$x_n = x_{n-1} - \frac{(y_{n-2}-y_{n-1})(x_{n-1}-x_{n-3})^2+(y_{n-1}-y_{n-3})(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})^2}{2((y_{n-2}-y_{n-1})(x_{n-1}-x_{n-3})+(y_{n-1}-y_{n-3})(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}))}$$

Hope this helps!